# Using a typedef as a variable name not generating any error

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

Considering this structure of data:

```
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
} point;
```

And i'm using this function to permute the coordinates:

```
point permute(point M)
{
    point N;
    N.x = M.y;
    N.y = M.x;
    return N;
}
```

Why is declaring a variable with the name (`point`) which is a `typedef` not giving any error?

```
int main(void)
{
point A;
point B;
int point = 7;

A.x = 0;
A.y = 1;
B = permute(A);

printf("A (%.2f, %.2f)\n", A.x, A.y);
printf("B (%.2f, %.2f)\n", B.x, B.y);
printf("point = %d\n", point);

return 0;
}
```

Output: http://ideone.com/wCxbjD

```
A (0.00, 1.00)
B (1.00, 0.00)
point = 7
```

Comment: Isn't the second declaration a confliction with the typedef name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scope.

An identifier declared in an outer scope (in your case, at file scope, i.e., outside any function) may be redeclared in an inner scope (in your case, inside the `main` function). The inner declaration *hides* the outer declaration until you reach the end of the inner scope.

This applies to declarations in general, not just to `typedef` names.

A simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { int x, y; } point;

int main(void) {
    point p = { 10, 20 };
    /* p is of type point */

    int point = 42;
    /* This hides the typedef; the name "point"
       now refers to the variable */

    printf("p = (%d, %d), point = %d\n", p.x, p.y, point);
    /* p is still visible here; its type name "point" is not
       because it's hidden. */
}
```

The output is:

```
p = (10, 20), point = 42
```

If we modified the above program to move the `typedef` into the same scope as the variable declaration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    typedef struct { int x, y; } point;
    point p = { 10, 20 };
    int point = 42;
    printf("p = (%d, %d), point = %d\n", p.x, p.y, point);
}
```

we'd get an error; gcc says:

```
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:5:9: error: ‘point’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
c.c:3:34: note: previous declaration of ‘point’ was here
```

(The C language *could* have been defined to permit this, with the second declaration of `point` hiding the first for the rest of the scope, but the designers apparently felt that hiding declarations from outer scopes could be useful, but doing so within a single scope would cause more confusion than it's worth.)

A slightly more complex example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    typedef struct { int x, y; } point;
    { /* Create an inner scope */
        point p = { 10, 20 };
        /* Now the type name is hidden */
        int point = 42;
        printf("p = (%d, %d), point = %d\n", p.x, p.y, point);
    }
    /* We're outside the scope of `int point`, so the type name is
       visible again */

    point p2 = { 30, 40 };
    printf("p2 = (%d, %d)\n", p2.x, p2.y);
}
```

Such hiding is probably not the best idea; using the same name for two different things, though it's no problem for the compiler, can be confusing to human readers. But it allows you to use names at block scope without having to worry about all the names that might have been introduced at file scope by all the headers you've include`.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize you could even declare a typedef anywhere other than the root scope.

Comment: I was under the impression that scoping was only used for variable names. I am now enlightened.

Comment: This is a good question and answer that would benefit with some more good/bad examples than shown by OP.

Comment: @chux: I added some examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a question of scope:

```
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
} point;

point point = {2.0, 3.0};
```

gives an error

```
blo.c:6:7: error: ‘point’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
point point = {2.0, 3.0};
      ^
blo.c:4:3: note: previous declaration of ‘point’ was here
 } point;
```

whereas

```
void blo() {
  typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
  } point;

  {
    point point = {2.0, 3.0};
  }
}
```

is legal.